# Proof that $(2K^2-b^2)^{1/2} \subseteq\frac{x^2-2}{(z+y)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

I figured out a interest property when trying to solve:

> Create a sequence such that $K,a,b$ is an integer and the Greatest Common Denominator of $a \hspace{2mm}\&\hspace{2mm} b=1$;
>   $$K=(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2})^{1/2}$$

I began solving this by creating algorithm that produces a list for all of the possible "$a$" values over a given range.

List of $a$ in range $(0,450)$ from my Python Algorithm

> 1, 7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97, 113, 119, 127, 161, 167, 191, 199, 217, 223, 233, 241, 281, 287, 329, 337, 343, 353, 359, 383, 391, 433, 439, 449

I then started looking up similar sequence and found [A253408](https://oeis.org/A253408) :

> Find $x,y,z$ such that each variable is a integer.  $$z^2+2=y^2+x^2$$

List of $(z-y)$ in range $(0,450)$ from [A253408](https://oeis.org/A253408)

> 1, 7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97, 103, 113, 119, 127, 137, 151, 161, 167, 191, 193, 199, 217, 223, 233, 239, 241, 257, 263, 271, 281, 287, 289, 311, 313, 329, 337, 343, 353, 359, 367, 383, 391, 401, 409, 431, 433, 439, 449

Upon comparing these two I noticed that all of the numbers in the list of $a$'s exist in list for number in $(z-y)$'s or $a\subseteq (z-y)$.  My first question is why does this work?

Also.

$z^2+2=x^2+y^2$, so $(z-y)=\frac{x^2-2}{(z+y)}$

$K=(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2})^{1/2}$, so $a=(2K^2-b^2)^{1/2}$

This means that if
$a \subseteq(z-y)$ is True. Then $(2K^2-b^2)^{1/2}\subseteq\frac{x^2-2}{(z+y)}$ must also be true

My second question is,  Is $(2K^2-b^2)^{1/2}\subseteq\frac{x^2-2}{(z+y)}$ a known equation?

Comment: I just came in to ask what $=_\rightarrow^\rightarrow$ means.

Comment: @Batominovski The the right side of the $\rightarrow$, have results that can be found in the left side.  It's like $\{1,2,3\}=^\rightarrow_\rightarrow\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ because 1,2,3 exist in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  It is my own notation so I don't use it like everyone knows what you mean.

Comment: How is this different from $\{1,2,3\}\subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing all the work for you - where would be the fun in that! -

Looking at this modulo 4 casts a lot of light on the situation.

For any non-negative integers $x,y,z$:

$x^2\equiv 0$ or $1\pmod 4$

So $x^2+y^2\equiv 0,1$ or $2\pmod 4$,

and $z^2+2\equiv 2$ or $3\pmod 4$

So for $x^2+y^2$ to equal $z^2+2$, both sides must be $\equiv 2\pmod 4$.

So $x,y,x^2$ and $y^2$ must all be $\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

And $z^2$ must be $\equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

Also, any $K^2$ is $\equiv 0$ or $1\pmod 4$, so any $2K^2$ must be $\equiv 0$ or $2 \pmod 4$.

So if $a^2+b^2=2K^2$, $a,b,a^2$ and $b^2$ must all be either $\equiv0\pmod 4$ or all $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. You've specified that they're odd, so they're all $\equiv 1\pmod 4$. So $K$ and $K^2$ are $\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Etc. The two systems share many of the same properties.

p.s. It took me a while to realize what you were talking about; it's written in an atrociously bad style!